# List all sequences in HsqlDB 1.8

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

How can I **list all sequences** in a specific schema in **HsqlDB 1.8**?

Note: HsqlDB 1.8 does **NOT** support the information_schema tables introduced in 2.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.system_sequences
```

Comment: @fredt: I thought in 2.x the sequences are stored in `information_schema.sequences`

Comment: NB that doing this select also "describes" all the various sequences, like the min/max/current values, FWIw.